# How to read a file and save the contents till we encounter the first blank line in perl script

Tags: perl, foreach

I am trying to read a file and save the lines which starts with $path till it encounters first balnk line in an array. I have the below code, bt it only prints the path name and not the lines. Could some-one have a look.

```
Below are the contents of the $file:

\sbd\archieve\date\form
-rwxrwxrwx 1 etd maadm 4354270 Aug 16 21:56 COMAHCUT.dat.20120816.ftpd.201208162156*
-rw-r--r-- 1 etd maadm       0 Aug 16 21:56 COMAHCUT.DONE.20120816.ftpd.201208162156

\sbd\single\archieve\date\form
-rwxr-xr-x 1 etd maadm 1362780 Aug 15 22:02 COMAINS.dat.ftpd.201208152203*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 etd maadm       0 Aug 15 22:02 COMAINS.DONE.ftpd.201208152203*

Below is the code i tried:
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $file = "/home/pauler/practice/DataIt/line.txt";
open (INFO, $file) or die "Cannot open the file $file :$! \n";
my $path = "\sbd\archieve\date\form";

foreach $line (<INFO>) {
        if ($line =~ m/$path/) {
        push (@array1, $line);
        last if ($line =~ m/^$/);
        print @array1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact, that filehandles remember their position in the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;
my $path = '\sbd\archieve\date\form';

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next unless $line =~ /\Q$path\E/;
    push @array, $line;
    while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
        last if $line =~ /^\s*$/;
        push @array, $line;
    }
}

print @array;

__DATA__
\sbd\archieve\date\form
-rwxrwxrwx 1 etd maadm 4354270 Aug 16 21:56 COMAHCUT.dat.20120816.ftpd.201208162156*
-rw-r--r-- 1 etd maadm       0 Aug 16 21:56 COMAHCUT.DONE.20120816.ftpd.201208162156

\sbd\single\archieve\date\form
-rwxr-xr-x 1 etd maadm 1362780 Aug 15 22:02 COMAINS.dat.ftpd.201208152203*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 etd maadm       0 Aug 15 22:02 COMAINS.DONE.ftpd.201208152203*
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked and majorly it was successfully . thanks a lott @tauli

Answer (score 1):

The flip-flop operator `..` saves life ... our you code. It stays false until the expression on the left returns true, and remains true until the expression on the right turns true ... then it is false again until the left expressions evaluates to true again.

```
# read lines into $_ for cleaner code
while (<INFO>) {
    if (/$path/ .. /^$/) {
       push @array1, $_;
    }
}
print @array1;
```

Oh, and a note on paths ... I know no single Operating System that really needs backslashes, not even Windows … Using normal slashes `/` will save you from weird escape sequences and other magic that lurks in the dark

Comment: This gives me the o/p as \sbd\archieve\date\form -rwxrwxrwx 1 etd maadm 4354270 Aug 16 21:56COMAHCUT.dat.20120816.ftpd.201208162156* \sbd\archieve\date\form -rwxrwxrwx 1 etd maadm 4354270 Aug 16 21:56 COMAHCUT.dat.20120816.ftpd.201208162156*
 -rw-r--r-- 1 etd maadm 0 Aug 16 21:56 COMAHCUT.DONE.20120816.ftpd.201208162156

Comment: i mean i get the path and then the 1st line followed by path and den the 2lines.

Comment: @pauler As @tripleee pointed out, the `@array1` gets printed to often. Correcting now…